VBA change shape color depending on drop down value selected
I am attempting to change 6 circle segments (the appear as pie chart) that are all currently red. I have named each of the segment shapes.
Depending on the drop down value selected on my worksheet 'Dashboard' in cell o5, I want the circle colours to change. If the 1st option "Option 1" is selected, I just want 1 piece of segment to change to black. If the 2nd option "Option 2" is selected, I want 2 pieces of the segments to change to black, and so on.
My circle segments are on a different worksheet called 'Project Tracker'.
Im not getting any errors, but also nothing is happening.
Any advice would be appreciated.
   Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$O$5" And Target.Parent.Name = "Dashboard" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case "Option 1"
    Worksheets("Project tracker").Shapes("RT1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Case "Option 2"
    Worksheets("Project tracker").Shapes("RT1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Worksheets("Project Tracker").Shapes("RT2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Case "Option 3"
    Worksheets("Project tracker").Shapes("RT1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Worksheets("Project tracker").Shapes("RT2").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Worksheets("Project tracker").Shapes("RT3").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End Select
    End If
    End Sub

(I did also try it with 'If Target.Address = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("$O$5") Then)

Is this code in the Dashboard sheet code module?

I had not - spot on BigBen thank you

Something like this should work (put it in the code module for "Dashboard")
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, v, n As Long
    If Target.Address <> "$O$5" Then Exit Sub 'cell of interest?
    
    v = Target.Value
    'get selected option, or if cell is empty then set n=0 to set all back to red
    n = IIf(Len(v) > 0, CLng(Right(v, 1)), 0)
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project tracker")
        For i = 1 To 6
            'choose color based on value of n
            .Shapes("RT" & i).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(i <= n, vbBlack, vbRed)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

